# With CSS, style a div's text node (innerText), and exclude if it's a p element

Tags: css

Given the following HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  should be bold (text node)
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    should be bold
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3>
    should be bold
  </h3>
  <p>
    should not be bold
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    should not be bold
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p>
      should not be bold
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following styles the text node, but then also styles ALL descendants:

```css
.container {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The following almost does the trick, except that 'A. should be bold' is not bold:

```scss
.container {
  &:first-child:not(p) {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

As soon as you use a selector, such as `.container *`, then the innerText will get excluded:

```scss
.container {
  * {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

I know this can easily be done with a class '.bold', but it needs to be dynamic. And ideally without overriding any styles because in the application the element get's some additional styling as well which I don't want to have to overwrite.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
.container {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.container p{
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Edit :

I will suggest this, but if you put just some text it will rendered like it has a <p>...

```css
.container *:not(p) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  A. should be bold
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3>B. should be bold</h3>
  <p>C. should not be bold</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>D. should not be bold</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah good one. Yes. I've added some additional information. Ideally there would be a way without having to overwrite the font-weight property.

Comment: Thanks. But the example provided does not style the first scenario (A.), where a text is just added plainly in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar example: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-target-only-the-stray-text-inside-a-div/

So it seems you cannot target text nodes individually:

> *"You can’t select text nodes to style them. CSS basically selects elements"*

So I guess it's not possible without using an element.

Answer (score 0):

When wanting a child element to have an alternate or conflicting CSS style from it's parent, the code you would want to run is as follows.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  should be bold
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    should be bold
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3>
    should be bold
  </h3>
  <p>
    should not be bold
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    should not be bold
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.container > p {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

[image]